# Convert string to packed data in Python

Tags: python

My goal is convert an address string to packed data in Python. For example:

```
address = '7fffde53bf80'             #input
formated  = '\x80\xbf\x53\xde\xff\x7f' #desired output
```

I wrote a simple script to accomplish this.

```
x = range(len(address))
evn = [e for e in x if e % 2 == 0][::-1] #reverse the list
formated = ''
i = 0
while(i < len(evn)):
    formated = formated + r'\x' + address[evn[i]:evn[i] + 2]
    i = i + 1
print formated
```

I'm sure there will be a better way to do this in python. Can anyone suggest me how to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `str.decode()` to decode the hex values to bytes, then reverse:

```
address.decode('hex')[::-1]
```

Demo:

```
>>> address = '7fffde53bf80'
>>> address.decode('hex')[::-1]
'\x80\xbfS\xde\xff\x7f'
```

Comment: @Sanket : Note that this doesn't seem to work properly on Python 2.6.6: bytes in the printable ASCII range (\x20 - \x7e) decode to their printable form. Hopefully, this won't be an issue for you.

Comment: @PM2Ring: don't confuse byte values with their representation. All versions of Python will show the printable character rather than an escape sequence when available.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Ah, ok. It's just that your demo code above prints `'\x80\xbfS\xde\xff\x7f'` on my system. But I guess that doesn't matter for the OP's application.

Comment: @PM2Ring: No for me it does not matter. I'm writing the output of `str.decode()` to a file and when I open the file in hex editor it is exactly how I want it to be